# Cypher query and multi-pass references

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following Cypher query that looks for the `Permission` for `User` via `Role`:

```
MATCH (p:Permission)<-[:CONTAINS]-(r:Role)<-[:HAS]-(u:User) 
WHERE u.id = {userId} AND p.type = {permissionType} AND p.code = {permissionCode} 
RETURN p
```

This query works fine.

Also, the `User` can have a direct relationship with the `Permission`:

```
(p:Permission)<-[:HAS]-(u:User)
```

How to extend the original query in order to also look for the `Permission` that is directly associated with the `User`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this :

```
MATCH (p:Permission)<-[:HAS|:CONTAINS*1..2]-(u:User) 
WHERE u.id = {userId} AND p.type = {permissionType} AND p.code = {permissionCode} 
RETURN p
```

Cheers